# Manipulate spreadsheets and User Interface(Widget,..) in API Excel Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

can I add some action when manipulating the spreadsheet in excel Even api-js?
for example: I try to use OnSelectionChanged Event with form datepicker (JQuery form, ...) to select the date for the cell with the same statement as:

```
$ ('cell'). datepicker ();
```

but i think it won't work.
Can someone tell me whether this is possible ?
Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your post,

In our design, we cannot listen the event from external widget directly, but if the selection is made with in Excel, the event will be triggered. 
in your case, i think you want to know what new date input by the widget, therefore, you could listen the onChanged event. here is the document for your reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onchanged

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My idea is that when I select the box, datepicker form display is near by the cell. And when I select the date from the datepicker, Cell value will change accordingly. instead of having to choose date in the widget.Whether it is possible?

Comment: I am not sure if datepicker have an interface for you to listen to event from it? if you have that, it may possible. otherwise, in current design, we don't support.

Comment: thank you for the helpful information. i will try some other ideas!